# RegEx - Pipe (vertical bar) (|) at the end of parenthesis / just before closing parenthesis

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I came across today with this regex in jQuery [source code](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js) - line 66 (and some other places) and I couldn't find anything about it.

```
// Used for matching numbers
[+-]?(?:\d*\.|)\d+(?:[eE][+-]?\d+|)
```

As far as I can tell it (`(stuff|)`) matches `stuff` or `empty string` and I think it is same with this

```
[+-]?(?:\d*\.)?\d+(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?
```

I benchmarked it in [here](http://regexhero.net/tester/) and it was not stable (with toleration of 15k) so.. Unreliable?

So what is the deal with those two regexes? A matter of choice? Performance? Different meanings?

Comment: I think they're equivalent. It's probably just a programmer who didn't know about optional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I advice you to use debuggex when you're having a hard time understanding a regex :

```
[+-]?(?:\d*\.|)\d+(?:[eE][+-]?\d+|)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/wkHGObWW3NEL8gv3)

```
[+-]?(?:\d*\.)?\d+(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ZIymVCuKqPsL3_W_)

Result : they've got the same meaning.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and the demos. Great tool